# ajaxtoolkit fileupload event after upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using ajax toolkit fileupload for uploading images. I would like to add an event. Such as response.redirect after last image is uploadet. How will this be possible?

Tried with OnUploadCompleteAll but without any luck

### Thanks

Code:

```
OnUploadComplete="File_Upload"

protected void File_Upload(object sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    //SAVE UPLOADED FILES 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `UploadCompleteAll` event.

That will fire after the all the files are uploaded.

Just type `OnUploadCompleteAll` and press tab twice. A event handler will be put up by visual studio.

Do whatever you want in that handler

Comment: Sorry forgot to write. I have tried this event without any luck

Comment: OnUploadCompleteAll="Upload_End"

Comment: protected void Upload_End(object sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
    }

Comment: Am i wrong? The tab twice does not have effect. Thanks

Comment: Using ajax toolkit v. 4, 1, 60919, 0

Answer (score 0):

When using `UploadCompleteAll`, the event args type should be `AjaxFileUploadCompleteAllEventArgs` not `AjaxFileUploadEventArgs`.

```
protected void Upload_End(object sender, AjaxFileUploadCompleteAllEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks. When changing the event arggs type i get red error under: The type of namespace does not exist. Is there somthing wrong with my bin ?

Comment: @user2761009 did you put the following on the top of the page: `using AjaxControlToolkit;`

Comment: @user2761009 No problem. so it is okay now? Please accept an answer if you can so we know everything worked out for you!

Comment: Sorry for making me unclear. NO. It will not work okay. OnUploadComplete works. UploadCompleteAll is not working. Is UploadCompleteAll new feature in ajax toolkit fileupload?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your AjaxUploadControl:

```
OnClientUploadComplete="ClientUploadComplete"
```

Then this part stays as is on server side:

```
AjaxFileUpload1.Attributes.Add("OnClientUploadComplete", "Return  OnClientUploadComplete");
```

Last part is to add this to your client side scripts:

```
        function ClientUploadComplete() {
        var f = $(".filename").html();
        window.location.replace("upload.aspx?filename=" + f);
    }
```